# Play/Stop sound from another activity

Tags: android, audio, transition

I have 3 activities. I want to play one background music to all this activity. I made this possible by. Doing this.

In activity 1:

```
bgmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);
bgmp.setLooping(true);
bgmp.start();
```

This will make my music play up to the 3rd acitivity. At activity three. I need to stop this background music because another background music will be played when I go to the 4th activity. How can I stop the music at the 3rd acitivity that was created at the 1st activity. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define Method in common class with require parameters and use that Method in your activities.

```
public class CommonMethod {
public static MediaPlayer player;
    public static void SoundPlayer(Context ctx,int raw_id){
            player = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, raw_id);
            player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
            player.setVolume(100, 100);

            //player.release();
             player.start();
        }
}
```

Within in your third activity, code for stop media.

> CommonMethod.player.stop();

Comment: What should I pass in the int raw_id?

Comment: CommonMethod.SoundPlayer(this, R.raw.menu);

Comment: Would the instance of this class at my first activity be different in the third class? For example: At the first activity, I will create a instance of the common class as cc, then cc.SoundPlayer(this, R.raw.menu) to play the music. At the third activity, will I be able to stop the music that was created at the 1st activity by just instantiating the common class ex: cc, and use this code. cc.player.stop();? Thank you in advance!

Comment: check I updated my answer, simply call `CommonMethod.player.stop();` in your third activity

Answer (score 1):

Create a service to play sound and move all your player code to service.

After that bind your activity to this service and control the music player for (play next, back, pause, stop etc.) features.

Answer (score 1):

Make a singleton class and add you music playing code into it for stopping and starting and use that singleton class in all your 3 activities for eg:

```
public class MusicManager {

    private static MusicManager refrence = null;

    public static MusicManager getInstance(){
        if(refrence == null){
            refrence = new MusicManager ();
        }
        return refrence;
    }

}
```

add a public method to this singleton class to start and stop music like

```
public void initalizeMediaPlayer(Context context, int musicId){

// add initalization of media player in it and loop it 
}

public void startPlaying(){
// add code to start playing music
}

public void stopPlaying(){
// add code to stop playing music
}
```

And for making use this class use like this

```
MusicManager.getInstance().initalizeMediaPlayer(this, R.raw.menu); // to initalize of media player
MusicManager.getInstance().startPlaying();// to start playing music
MusicManager.getInstance().stopPlaying(); // to stop playing music
```

Let me know if this helps you.
Mean while you can also use `service` to perform this task as `service` runs in background . you can start `service` and stop `service` any time in your code

Answer (score 0):

You Should Start Service which runs in background and write code for playing music in the service..

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add this piece of code to your intent to the last activity:

`yourMediaPlayer.pause()`

So the whole code would be :

```
yourMediaPlayer.pause();
Intent i ...
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `player.stop()` function inside button which takes you to next activity:

```
example: @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                player.stop();
                Intent i=new Intent(iotmain.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Chatting mode ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```